# Exclude IDs who don't show up every week

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this data-frame:

```
  ID        date   var
 123  01/12/2020  0.22
 123  09/12/2020  0.73
 123  14/12/2020  0.24
 123  15/12/2020  0.03
 123  23/12/2020  0.51
 123  25/12/2020  0.66
 456  09/12/2020  0.18
 456  14/12/2020  0.55
 456  15/12/2020  0.72
 456  23/12/2020  0.54
 456  25/12/2020  0.16
 789  01/12/2020  0.62
 789  09/12/2020  0.95
 789  23/12/2020  0.24
 789  25/12/2020  0.66
 987  30/11/2020  0.49
 987  09/12/2020  0.89
 987  14/12/2020  0.35
 987  23/12/2020  0.66
 987  25/12/2020  0.82
```

I want to exclude IDs who don't have an observation every week from `November 30, 2020` to `December 27, 2020`, where "week" starts from Monday and ends on Sunday.

Expected results:

```
  ID        date   var
 123  01/12/2020  0.22
 123  09/12/2020  0.73
 123  14/12/2020  0.24
 123  15/12/2020  0.03
 123  23/12/2020  0.51
 123  25/12/2020  0.66
 987  30/11/2020  0.49
 987  09/12/2020  0.89
 987  14/12/2020  0.35
 987  23/12/2020  0.66
 987  25/12/2020  0.82
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is create set of all possible `week` and test if all matching per groups:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)

s = pd.to_datetime('November 30, 2020')
e = pd.to_datetime('December 27, 2020')

r = set(pd.date_range(s, e).isocalendar().week.unique())

f = lambda x: r == set(x)
mask = df['date'].dt.isocalendar().week.groupby(df['ID']).transform(f)

df = df[mask]
print (df)
     ID       date   var
0   123 2020-12-01  0.22
1   123 2020-12-09  0.73
2   123 2020-12-14  0.24
3   123 2020-12-15  0.03
4   123 2020-12-23  0.51
5   123 2020-12-25  0.66
15  987 2020-11-30  0.49
16  987 2020-12-09  0.89
17  987 2020-12-14  0.35
18  987 2020-12-23  0.66
19  987 2020-12-25  0.82
```

Another idea is get index values if all values exist for `ID` with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)

s = pd.to_datetime('November 30, 2020')
e = pd.to_datetime('December 27, 2020')

r = pd.date_range(s, e).isocalendar().week.unique()
print (r)

df['week'] = df['date'].dt.isocalendar().week

idx = (df.drop_duplicates(['ID','week'])
       .pivot_table(index='ID', columns='week', aggfunc='size')
       .reindex(r, axis=1)
       .notna()
       .all(axis=1))

df = df[df['ID'].isin(idx.index[idx])]
print (df)
```

Comment: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'isocalendar'

Comment: @qwerty - This solution working in last pandas versions, can you remove `.isocalendar()` for working in oldier versions?

Comment: It takes a lot of time since it's big data. Any suggestion to increase running time? I mean, changing the solution to be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for 6 different observations for every customer:

```
complete_weeks_ID   = (df.groupby(ID).date.count() == 6)
IDs_w_complete_info = complete_weeks_ID[complete_weeks_ID].index.tolist() 

df[df.ID.isin(IDs_w_complete_info)]
```